# How can I change filename in the formula in Excel to be refreshed in every cell in the table?

Tags: excel

I have this formula in a big excel file: I'm using another Excel file.

='C:\2020 february[file1.xlsx]sheet'!F15 + 'C:\2020 february[file1.xlsx]sheet2'!F15

I want to refresh this formula everywhere in my table:
 from: 2020 february ------> to: 2020 march
 from: file1 -------> to: file2

How can I do it the easiest way?
It's not possible to change in first cell and shift it because there are lots of rows where another formula are used.

Thanks.

Comment: The Edit Links dialog allows you to change the source of an external link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Find and Replace (Ctl + H) and make sure to click the **Options** button and select **Formulas** in the drop-down for **Look in:**

[image]